# How do I add a column in a dataframe in python whose value depends on multiple columns

Tags: python

say I want to add a column called as "Category". It takes value "1" if the value of another column "High" holds the value "True", otherwise, it takes the value "2" if another column "Medium" holds value "true" otherwise, it takes up "0".
Note:- High, medium, and low are already present columns that have value as either "True" or "False".
I need code in Python

Comment: Hello Manish, what have you tried? Let us know so we can help you with your previous attempts

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topics].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def getValue(index, df):
    if df['high'][index]:
        return 1
    if df['medium'][index]:
        return 2
    return 0

df = pd.DataFrame({'medium':[True,False,True,False],'high':[True, True, False, False],'low':[False, False, True, True]})

df['Category'] = [ getValue(index,df) for index in range(len(df.values)) ]
```

this results in:

```
    medium  high    low     Category
0   True    True    False   1
1   False   True    False   1
2   True    False   True    2
3   False   False   True    0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's knind of unclear what you mean. But I think you want something like this...

```
"""
        Name        Type 1  Type 2  HP  AT  DE  SpA SpD Spe Gen Legendary
0   1   Bulbasaur   Grass   Poison  45  49  49  65  65  45  1   False
1   2   Ivysaur     Grass   Poison  60  62  63  80  80  60  1   False
2   3   Venusaur    Grass   Poison  80  82  83  100 100 80  1   False
.....................................................................
"""
```

Say we had this data frame, and you wanted the sum of HP, AT and DE as a new column. Then we could do something like this...

```
# df['Total']  This will tell us what we want the new column to be called.
# df.iloc[:, 4:7] The : will select the whole row. and 4:7 will get the values of the 
# colums. So were only getting HP, AT, DE as ints.
# And .sum will get the sum of the three. And axis=1 represents columns
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 4:7].sum(axis=1)
```

Or...

```
df['Total'] = df['HP'] + df["AT"] + df["DE"]
```

So Then the data frame should like something like this...

```
"""
        Name        Type 1  Type 2  HP  AT  DE  SpA SpD Spe Gen Legendary Total
0   1   Bulbasaur   Grass   Poison  45  49  49  65  65  45  1   False     143
1   2   Ivysaur     Grass   Poison  60  62  63  80  80  60  1   False     185
2   3   Venusaur    Grass   Poison  80  82  83  100 100 80  1   False     245
.....................................................................
  (These are the columns we added)  ^^  ^^  ^^  (And now the sum is here) ^^^
"""
```

If you're using bools, you could just use a different method like...

```
df['High HP'] = (df['HP'] > 100)  # Create a new column with a value based off the "HP" column.
```